# Unable to deploy Elastic Beanstalk Application with mounted Elastic File System

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-efs

I am in the process of migrating a Node.js application from the deprecated Amazon Linux 1 platform to an Amazon Linux 2 platform.

Everything works, up until I attempt to mount the EFS following the [exact directions provided by Amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-mount-efs-volumes/). If I do not include this script (modified with the appropriate values), the Node app deploys (using `eb deploy`) and all parts that are not dependent on the EFS work as expected.

Once I include the script, I receive the following error and the deployment fails -

```
[ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [PreBuildEbExtension]. Stop running the command. Error: EbExtension build failed. Please refer to /var/log/cfn-init.log for more details.
```

When running on the Linux 1 platform, I experienced no issues with this EFS script and variables. I have tried using a larger EC2 instance, and that has not worked (t2.small instead of a t2.micro).

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be incorrectly set security groups.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more? Your answer does not explain much. What rules were missing? Why? Any link to some references on how the SGs should be setup?